# NTILE a column in csv - Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a csv file that reads like this:

```
a,b,c,2
d,e,f,3
g,h,i,3
j,k,l,4
m,n,o,5
p,q,r,6
s,t,u,7
v,w,x,8
y,z,zz,9
```

I want to assign quintiles to this data (like we do it in sql), using preferably bash command in linux. The quintiles, if assigned as a new column, will make the final output look like:

```
a,b,c,2, 1
d,e,f,3, 1
g,h,i,3, 2
j,k,l,4, 2
m,n,o,5, 3
p,q,r,6, 3
s,t,u,7, 4
v,w,x,8, 4
y,z,z,9, 5
```

The only thing i am able to achieve is to add a new incremental column to the csv file:

```
`awk '{$3=","a[$3]++}1' f1.csv > f2.csv`
```

But not sure how do the quintiles. Please help. thanks.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus I understand. Since my knowledge of awk is very limited..the only thing i am able to succeed in is to add a new column to assign incremental ranks to the rows of the csv file. I will add the script in. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}
     END{
       for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) {
         p=100/NR*i
         q=1
         if(p>20){q=2}
         if(p>40){q=3}
         if(p>60){q=4}
         if(p>80){q=5}
         print a[i] ", " q
       }
     }' file
```

Output:

```
a,b,c,2, 1
d,e,f,3, 2
g,h,i,3, 2
j,k,l,4, 3
m,n,o,5, 3
p,q,r,6, 4
s,t,u,7, 4
v,w,x,8, 5
y,z,zz,9, 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Short `wc` + `awk` approach:

```
awk -v n=$(cat file | wc -l) \
'BEGIN{ OFS=","; n=sprintf("%.f\n", n*0.2); c=1 }
 { $(NF+1)=" "c }!(NR % n){ ++c }1' file
```

- `n=$(cat file | wc -l)` - get the total number of lines of the input file `file`
- `n*0.2` - 1/5th (20 percent) of the range
- `$(NF+1)=" "c` - set next last field with current *rank* value `c`

---

The output:

```
a,b,c,2, 1
d,e,f,3, 1
g,h,i,3, 2
j,k,l,4, 2
m,n,o,5, 3
p,q,r,6, 3
s,t,u,7, 4
v,w,x,8, 4
y,z,zz,9, 5
```